# Unable to fill dropdown from within a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am calling a javascript function from codebehind using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "pop", "<script>alert('File Size Can Not Exceed 400Kb Limit.');window.onload = function () {RetainValues(); }</script>", false);
```

Here `RetainValues();` is a javascript function which is supposed to set the values of input and select controls on the form.

I have another function called `GetDropDownData()` which is responsible for fetching dropdown data from database (ajax call) and  filling the dropdown.

```
RetainValues(){
GetDropDownData();
   $(field).find("option").length; // this is always zero when i debug
//i would like to set selected option based on text here but since it seems to be zero here ,i cant.
}

function GetDropDownData(){
// ajax call to fecth data and fill dropdown
}
```

as soon as the RetainValues() function is completed i the dropdown gets filled. Since it does not get filled within the scope of RetainValues() i am not able to set its value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, since you are calling the `GetDropDownData` which contains the Ajax call, it is asynchronous.  This means you cannot tell when the ajax call is going to be complete.  1 second or 1 minute potentially!  However the javascript is immediately trying to find the length of the options which is returned before the ajax call has had a chance to complete.

You can only ascertain whether the options have indeed populated once your ajax call has completed.  This can be done in the `success` function of the ajax call or you can pass a callback function to the `success` function to be called which then does whatever you need doing on the basis that the ajax call has returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
RetainValues(){
GetDropDownData(); 
}
   function GetDropDownData(){
   $.ajax({ url: "URL to call", 
       success: function(data){
            //fill the dropdown
             $(field).find("option").length;
            // U will get the exact length. Now u can do whatever u want using the Length.
        }
    });
}
```